# How to detect if Image has only wrong EXIF or Image should be rotated?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

We have some SharePoint environment and I have detected thousands images with wrong EXIF or wrong EXIF + Orientation. 
For example: 
a) there are many pictures with correct landscape orientation but with EXIF "6" 
b) there are also pictures, which sould be oriented as Portrait, but actually have landscape orientation and EXIF "6"
I need to be able to detect, if only EXIF needs to be changed or both EXIF + Orientation needs to be changed.

I have following code, but how to detect if image needs to only change EXIF or also needs to be rotated?

```cs
public static void SetImageProperties(System.Drawing.Image image, ImageFormat imageFormat, SPFile spFile, Enumerators.SPImageOrientations imageOrientation, bool rotate, RotateFlipType rotation)
{
    string loggingMessage = null;
    SPWeb spWeb = spFile.Item.ParentList.ParentWeb;
    string siteUrl = spWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl(spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl);
    List<PropertyItem> propertyItems = image.PropertyItems.OrderBy<PropertyItem, int>(pi => pi.Id).ToList<PropertyItem>();
    PropertyItem propertyItem = propertyItems.Where<PropertyItem>(property => property.Id == 274).FirstOrDefault<PropertyItem>();
    Int16 imageOrientationInt = Convert.ToInt16(imageOrientation);
    byte imageOrientationNumber = (byte)imageOrientationInt;
    if (propertyItem != null)
    {
        propertyItem.Value[0] = imageOrientationNumber;
        image.SetPropertyItem(propertyItem);
        Stream imageStream = DrawingMethods.ImageToStream(image, imageFormat);
        spFile.SaveBinary(imageStream);
        spWeb.Dispose();
        if (rotate == true)
        {
            SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteUrl);
            spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb();
            SPList spList = spWeb.Lists[spFile.Item.ParentList.ID];
            SPListItem spListItem = spList.GetItemById(spFile.Item.ID);
            spFile = spListItem.File;
            image = DrawingMethods.ByteArrayToImage(spFile.OpenBinary());
            image.RotateFlip(rotation);
            imageFormat = MimeTypeHelper.GetImageFormat(spFile.OpenBinary());
            imageStream = DrawingMethods.ImageToStream(image, imageFormat);
            spFile.SaveBinary(imageStream);
            spWeb.Dispose();
            spSite.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's no (easy) way to detect an image orientation other than read its EXIF data and check for the Orientation value.**

In your particular case, even if you have some information about the images *(ex: they are portrait/landscape images)*, you could not put up a simple solution. If **no Orientation value is defined** in its EXIF data, you would need some sort of **image recognition & analysis library** *(such OpenCV or similar)* **to guess the image orientation**: an image is just an image and orientation is more of a *"human concern"*.

However, if an image contains orientation EXIF data, you can easily read them and rotate the image as you want.

**How to get Orientation EXIF data:**

```
// EXIF data: orientation address.
public const int ImageOrientationId = 0x0112;

// here we use an enum for readability purposes
public enum ExifOrientations
{
    Unknown = 0,
    TopLeft = 1,
    TopRight = 2,
    BottomRight = 3,
    BottomLeft = 4,
    LeftTop = 5,
    RightTop = 6,
    RightBottom = 7,
    LeftBottom = 8
}

public static ExifOrientations ImageExifOrientation(Image img)
{
    // check if there's a value for ImageOrientationId address
    int orientation_index =
    Array.IndexOf(img.PropertyIdList, ImageOrientationId);

    // that means there's no orientation value
    if (orientation_index < 0) return ExifOrientations.Unknown;

    // otherwise, we cast it in our enum and return it
    return (ExifOrientations)
    img.GetPropertyItem(ImageOrientationId).Value[0];
}
```

**How to rotate an Image using Orientation EXIF data:**

```
ExifOrientations exifOrientation = ImageExifOrientation(image);

switch (exifOrientation)
{
    case ExifOrientations.TopLeft:
        // DO NOT OPERATE ON IT
    break;

    case ExifOrientations.TopRight:
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
    break;

    case ExifOrientations.BottomRight:
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
    break;

    case ExifOrientations.BottomLeft:
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
    break;

    case ExifOrientations.LeftTop:
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipY);
    break;

    case ExifOrientations.RightTop:
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    break;

    case ExifOrientations.RightBottom:
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
    break;

    case ExifOrientations.LeftBottom:
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your complex answer.
I was expecting it wouldn't be easy, and it wouldn't be possible to solve it OOTB with .NET.
I just didn't know if there was a DLL library that had methods on it.

The problem is that EXIF can "lie" to you.
You can have pictures with correct landscape orientation but with EXIF "6" (according my enum = left sided landscape).
But in this case the picture should have "1" (OriginalUP/TopLeft)

Comment: public enum SPImageOrientations
{
    OriginalRIGHT = 8,
    FlippedRIGHT = 7,
    OriginalLEFT = 6,
    FlippedLEFT = 5,
    FlippedDOWN = 4,
    OriginalDOWN = 3,
    FlippedUP = 2,
    OriginalUP = 1
}
```

Comment: (1) I think you have the rotation for cases 6 and 8 mixed up, [see the "F" examples here](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html). (2) After rotating the image, `image.RemovePropertyItem` should be called to remove the (now deprecated) EXIF flag.